# AWX enable admin role for user

Tags: privileges, ansible-awx

I'm using awx to monitor windows hosts via winrm.
I need to run a playbook with admin role, but don't want to provide the Administrator account(just enable admin role for my account).
Do you know how to enable it? Many thanks

---

- name: Run PowerShell script
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Execute PowerShell script
    win_shell: |
    C:\Users\note1\Desktop\repos\Clone_db.ps1 `-rollback "$rollback"`
    -version "$version" `
    become: yes

Answer (score 0):

You are missing information on this playbook. You only have `become`: yes but, I don't see anywhere were you define the type of connection you are using. Ansible uses different types like kerberos, credssp and so forth. Verify by looking at here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_setup.html and the admin permissions https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html

Here is another example https://opensource.com/article/19/2/ansible-windows-admin

Comment: Hi @iyami5, I'm running this playbook with AWX via winrm(already setup on AWX so don't need in playbook anymore). My account need to run the powershell script with administrator role, so I need to enable the admin role for my account(it's not built in account). Do you have any idea for this issue?